# Making three divs fit perfectly in a parent div

Tags: html, css, width

I have been building websites for *way* too long not to know how to do this. I'm embarrassed to ask. But I must.

---

I want a way to make any number of child divs within a parent div automatically span to the full width of the parent div.

My criteria for this fix are:

1. All of the child divs must be the exact same width
2. The width of the children divs must be responsive/dynamic
3. I would prefer a fix that doesn't involve sitting there and testing different percentages to find the exact percent width to prevent one of the children being wrapped or hidden (IE "display: if-there-was-an-easy-fix" instead of "width: 29.468749%")
4. I would love it if the fix would work with fixed margins and dynamic margins (margin: 10px *and* margin: 5%)

I'm 99% sure I knew the answer to this like a year ago but my current job requires that I work almost exclusively in tables, so I've forgotten how to do anything that isn't clunky and semantically disgusting.

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width: 29.468749%;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

#one {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

#two {
  margin: 0 5%;
  background-color: wheat;
}

#three {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="box" id="one">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="two">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `display: flex` on parent and `flex: 1` on child elements to get [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  /*display:block;*/
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  /*width: 29.468749%;*/
  /*display:inline-block;
    /*margin:0;
    padding:0;*/
  flex: 1;
  height: 200px;
  border: none;
}

#one {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

#two {
  margin: 0 5%;
  background-color: wheat;
}

#three {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="box" id="one">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="two">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup. Embarrassingly simple. I need to get out of these tables before I forget how to... everything else...

Comment: but you have to get rid all the unecessary code like the width

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you'll want to do is remove **[`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)** from the elements, and instead give them a **[`float: left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)**. From here you can get a 'default' full-width alignment by giving your elements a **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** of about `33.33%` each. This would total `99.99%`, which is 'close enough' to the full-width (unless you're on a screen of `10000px` width). To **ensure** it's perfect though, you can use the CSS **[`calc()` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** to ensure that it's **exactly** one third with `width: calc(100% / 3)`.

This will work for regular elements, but your second box also has `margin` on it, which also factors into the `width` calculation in accordance with the **[box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model)**. Because you're adding a `5%` margin on **both sides**, , you'll want to subtract a total of `10%` from the `width` calculation for this element. This can be done with `width: calc((100% / 3) - (5% * 2))`.

This gives you three equally wide elements, with one element having additional margins, as can be seen in the following:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

#one {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

#two {
  margin: 0 5%;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - (5% * 2));
  background-color: wheat;
}

#three {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="box" id="one">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="two">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="one">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to change the number of elements, you simply need to update the `3` in each of the `width` calculations to reflect the number of siblings. This can be made even easier with a **[CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)**, meaning you only have to update the CSS in one place:

```css
:root {
  --columns: 3;
}

#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width: calc(100% / var(--columns));
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

#one {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

#two {
  margin: 0 5%;
  width: calc((100% / var(--columns)) - (5% * 2));
  background-color: wheat;
}

#three {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="box" id="one">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="two">
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="one">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP asked `to make any number of child divs within a parent div automatically span to the full width of the parent div`. Not just 3.

Comment: ^ Simply change the division in the calculation to reflect how many children you have. I'll update my answer to explicitly state this, though I don't think that makes it worthy of a down-vote.

Comment: How about dynamic? It would be much easier to use flexbox model, than what you are suggesting.

Comment: @spirit -- I personally prefer this solution, and it achieves exactly what the OP asks for, additionally noting constraints. Considering it does both of those, I'm surprised you would down-vote it simply because it offers a different approach than your own. And for what it's worth, `flexbox` isn't supported in IE.

Comment: Man. If all you need is an upvote. There you go. `flexbox` is supported in IE from `11.0`

Comment: @obsidian age, my problem is that even if you say "margin: 0; padding: 0;" divs will wrap unless you do what I did above: sit there and test each decimal place for the perfect width. If you check out my code snippet, the 29.468749% isn't just random, it's the absolute widest I can make the divs before they wrap. It's just annoyingly time consuming... and I have no idea what's going on with the calculations, I've never used those in CSS before, but wouldn't you have to do ((100%-5%*2)/var(--columns))? Your current setup gives you 23.33 because you subtract the margin from each box's width, no?

Comment: Actually, I just realized the middle child would be skinnier because you end up redefining the width as 100% on the ID, then subtracting the margins from only the width of #two. Is it possible to set up a second variable for margins, then use a width on .box like "calc((100%-var(--margins))/var(--columns))"?